# Quartz component not invoking the camel processor on Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, quartz-scheduler

I have created Simple JBossFUSE spring boot application with following dependencies

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>sample.fuse</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample-FUSE</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>springboot-camel-restdsl-api</name>
    <description>Camel SpringBoot REST API Example with REST DSL</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>sample.fuse.UrarepSpringBootApplication</start-class>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-servlet-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>mq-jms-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
            <version>9.2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Then I created simple RouteBuilder with following content

```
package sample.fuse.routebuilder;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.LoggingLevel;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import sample.fuse.process.*;

import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Component
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {
    static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyRouteBuilder.class);

    @Autowired
    TestProcessor testProcessor;

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {


        from("quartz://seasonParkingProcessorCron?cron=10+*+*+*+*+?&trigger.timeZone=America/Chicago&job.name=seasonParkingProcessorCron")
                .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "seasonParkingProcessorCron job kicked off")
                .process(testProcessor);

    }
}
```

Sample processor have following content.

```
package sample.fuse.process;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import sample.fuse.repository.MevEhtVideoImagesRepository;

import java.util.Calendar;

@Service
@Component
public class TestProcessor implements Processor {

    static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TestProcessor.class);

    @Autowired
    Environment environment;

    @Autowired
    private MevEhtVideoImagesRepository mevEhtVideoImagesRepository;

    public TestProcessor(){

    }

    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String body= (String) exchange.getIn().getBody();
        LOG.info("TestProcessor Called with exchange: " + body);
        System.out.println("AAAAAAAAAAAAAa");

        exchange.getOut().setBody(body+" "+ Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }

}
```

I'm expecting to call my Processor method every 10 seconds and print the log. However its giving following error on the log.

> 11:58:10,013 WARN  [org.apache.camel.component.quartz.QuartzEndpoint] (DefaultQuartzScheduler-camel-1_Worker-1) Cannot execute Quartz Job with context: JobExecutionContext: trigger: 'Camel.seasonParkingProcessorCron job: DEFAULT.seasonParkingProcessorCron fireTime: 'Thu Dec 21 11:58:10 SGT 2023 scheduledFireTime: Thu Dec 21 11:58:10 SGT 2023 previousFireTime: 'null nextFireTime: Thu Dec 21 11:59:10 SGT 2023 isRecovering: false refireCount: 0 because processor is not started: RoundRobinLoadBalancer

Anyone else experience this kind of error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use same version of the camel-core version for the camel-quartz. But in your pom file camel-core and camel-quartz versions should be matched.
Your camel-quartz dependency in pom file should be updated as following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-quartz</artifactId>
        <version>2.19.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

Then your MyRouteBuilder class configure method content need to changed as below.

```
        from("quartz://seasonParkingProcessorCron?cron=10+*+*+*+*+?")
            .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "seasonParkingProcessorCron job kicked off")
            .process(testProcessor);
```

Hope this will help to resolve your issue.